# Можно ли разбить значения в ArrayList на отдельные элементы

Tags: java, arraylist

У меня есть `ArrayList<String> mainLine`, в нем хранится под индексом `[0]` один элемент, например - `"hello"`. Можно ли разбить `"hello"` на отдельные элементы и переписать их в массив. То есть, `h - [0], e - [1]` и так далее. `НО` без громоздких решений, то есть без циклом и тому подобное. В идеале `1-3 строки` кода.

Comment: можно разбить вероятнее всего, в чём у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: У меня есть два класса - MainActivity и Algorithm. В классе Algorithm, есть метод со входными параметрами - public String mainMethod(ArrayList<String> mainLine) . В него из метода onClickStart которой в классе MainActivity, передаются значения. Передаю значения я с помощью вот этого -  out.setText(algorithm.mainMethod(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add(Значения); }} ));. Проблема в том, что таким способом, я записываю значения только под [0] индексом.  А мне надо, чтоб слова дробилось на части. [0] - h , [1] - o и тд.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `.flatMap`:

```
List<String> mainLine = asList("hello", "world");
List<Character> flat =
    mainLine.stream()
        .flatMap(str -> str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

На Kotlin можно. Вот так, например:

```
list.map{ it.split("").filter{ it.isNotEmpty() } }.flatten()
```

Проверка:

```
val list = listOf("hello", "world")
println(list)
val splitedList = list.map{ it.split("").filter{ it.isNotEmpty() } }.flatten()
println(splitedList)
```

Выведет:

> [hello, world]
> [h, e, l, l, o, w, o, r, l, d]

На Java можно аналогично, но я не знаю синтаксиса стримов, а гуглить некогда)